# Count time if values are in 00:00 format (nvarchar SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got this table:

table name: T

| total_time |
| --- |
| 8:45 |
| 2:45 |
| 1:45 |
| 5:43 |
| 17:45 |
| 10:54 |

etc.. etc...

How can I count the total number of rows of over 8 hours (more than 8:00)?
All values are nvarchar. How can I count the time in them?

when I use count(*) where total_time > '8:00' it counts the rows with more then 8:00 but less then 10:00.

Comment: for the table above the expected result is: 2
only 2 rows are more then 08:00 hours

Comment: What's the actual problem? Why not `select count(*) from T where total_time>'08:00'` ? The only problem in this question is that a text type is used to store something that's definitely not text.

Comment: SQL Server has no `interval` or `duration` type. A good option would be to use an `int` field to store durations in seconds or minutes. This would allow aggregations like SUM, MIN, etc, take less space and make both indexing and querying more efficient

Comment: `gives me whole of the times that are more than 1 hour.` no it doesn't. If that's all, the question should be closed as non-reproducible. Post an actual full example or a fiddile that demonstrates this - `CREATE TABLE` statement, `INSERT` with sample data and the actual query.

Comment: `StayTime` there's no such field in the question. Are you sure the problem is what you described? Perhaps you're searching using the wrong string, or some fields contain leading whitespace? That's why you *shouldn't* use text types to store durations

Comment: sorry panagiotis, check my question now. the main problem is that time less then 10:00 is listed in one digit 8:00 and not 08:00.

if I use > '8:00' it does not gives me the rows with more then 10:00. only the rows with more then 8:00 but less then 10:00

Comment: Putting the answer within the question is also not how this site works. Please stop trying to work around the restrictions of the site. Seriously ask yourself, do you think anyone else is going to find this question by searching for it, and then manage to solve the same problem? If the answer is no, then you've got your answer, don't worry about adding it.

Comment: Yes Dale I'm sorry but how can I answer it if the question is closed?

Comment: is it ok if in the future I will re-ask that question and answer it myself immediately ? so maybe it will help others in the future? and maybe earn so upvotes?

Comment: Not the same problem. Wait until you have a new problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you trust that every value is in a correct format and error-checking is not part of the task, you could also just go with:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM T
WHERE total_time >= '08:00';
```

Comment: hey I didnt downvoted you... but it doesnt work

Comment: The answer is bad for at least two reasons 1) Why use LEFT instead of just >='08:00` but worse 2) filtering based on the results of a function means indexes can't be used to speed up the query. In a table with 100K rows, using LEFT would force a scan of all 100K rows

Comment: Changed it for better sargability. Of course, both versions work entirely correct. Here is a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a77b1/1

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Valid points, I noticed that too, thanks.

Comment: @BenHeb this answer works. If you get unexpected results its because the data or the search term isn't what you assumed.

Comment: Using OP's "sample data" it doesn't work. You added a leading zero to "8:45" and that seemingly minor (but critical) change is what makes it "work".

Comment: @SMor that was the data in the original question, the OP changed the data afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question without extra details, you can try this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM [table_name]
WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, total_time) > 480
```

Comment: it gives me The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: @BenHeb Strange. As u can see in my tests with your data everything is ok: https://imgur.com/a/g1mFMAw

Comment: the times are Nvarchar: 8:45  -  6:23    - 12:45

Comment: Yes, they are nvarchar, u can see in the left where the table is defined the column type.

Comment: hey Dale how can I reopen the question? I  want to post an answer